# How to connect to multiple servers through ssh with different hosts & passwords in python?

Tags: python, ssh, parallel-ssh

How to connect to multiple servers through ssh with different hosts & passwords in python?

I've tried to use [Parallel-ssh](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh). But I was unable to connect to multiple servers that had a different password.

Example from there documentation for a single server:

```py
from pssh.clients import ParallelSSHClient

hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']

client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, user='my_user', password='my_pass')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [`fabric`](https://docs.fabfile.org). It provides similar functionality, but also allows you to manually create each connection and then pass them into a group. For example:

```
from fabric.connection import Connection
from fabric.group import SerialGroup, ThreadingGroup

config = {
    'host1': {'password': '...'},
    'host2': {'password': '...'},
}

connections = []
for hostname, parameters in config.items():
    conn = Connection(host=hostname, connect_kwargs=parameters)
    connections.append(conn)

with SerialGroup.from_connections(connections) as group:
    result = group.run('uname -a')

for conn, conn_result in result.items():
    print(conn, conn_result)
```